# CSOM + SharePoint Online - unable to get list item role assignments

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, role-assignment

I have made a very simple CSOM program where I have fetched a List Item and I have verified that it has `listItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments` = `true`

So with that being the case, I want to get the List Item role assignments. So I go ahead and attempt to fetch the role assignments using CSOM:

```
    clientContext.Load(listItem.RoleAssignments,
      ras => ras.Include(
          item => item.PrincipalId,
          item => item.Member.LoginName,
          item => item.Member.Title,
          item => item.Member.PrincipalType,
          item => item.RoleDefinitionBindings));
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

[Get the source code for the example here](https://gist.github.com/nddipiazza/d9bda1ce849f38ae537dba2f7f192111)

The result of this always returns an empty list.

**Here is the CSOM WCF XML Request from fiddler**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009" AddExpandoFieldTypeSuffix="true" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="16.0.0.0" ApplicationName=".NET Library">
   <Actions>
      <ObjectPath Id="34" ObjectPathId="33" />
      <Query Id="35" ObjectPathId="33">
         <Query SelectAllProperties="false">
            <Properties />
         </Query>
         <ChildItemQuery SelectAllProperties="false">
            <Properties>
               <Property Name="PrincipalId" ScalarProperty="true" />
               <Property Name="Member">
                  <Query SelectAllProperties="false">
                     <Properties>
                        <Property Name="LoginName" ScalarProperty="true" />
                        <Property Name="Title" ScalarProperty="true" />
                        <Property Name="PrincipalType" ScalarProperty="true" />
                     </Properties>
                  </Query>
               </Property>
               <Property Name="RoleDefinitionBindings" SelectAll="true">
                  <Query SelectAllProperties="false">
                     <Properties />
                  </Query>
               </Property>
            </Properties>
         </ChildItemQuery>
      </Query>
   </Actions>
   <ObjectPaths>
      <Property Id="33" ParentId="27" Name="RoleAssignments" />
      <Identity Id="27" Name="6b1fb39e-d0c3-7000-b3db-ec1021aca18d|740c6a0b-85e2-48a0-a494-e0f1759d4aa7:site:dc8ed2ac-dab3-4d38-a669-f2d9a8217dbf:web:9caa26cd-4dbb-43e0-9b41-26d384331bc5:list:83780af0-e908-4c51-a1be-49d7e0ac5867:item:2,1" />
   </ObjectPaths>
</Request>
```

CSOM WCF JSON Response (**This should have had list item role assignments but does not)**:

```
[
{
"SchemaVersion":"15.0.0.0","LibraryVersion":"16.0.8412.1210","ErrorInfo":null,"TraceCorrelationId":"6b1fb39e-d0c0-7000-b3db-e01045a23af0"
},34,{
"IsNull":false
},35,{
"_ObjectType_":"SP.RoleAssignmentCollection","_Child_Items_":[

]
}
]
```

Here is the list item:

```
{
    "_ObjectType_": "SP.ListItem",
    "_ObjectIdentity_": "6b1fb39e-d0c3-7000-b3db-ec1021aca18d|740c6a0b-85e2-48a0-a494-e0f1759d4aa7:site:dc8ed2ac-dab3-4d38-a669-f2d9a8217dbf:web:9caa26cd-4dbb-43e0-9b41-26d384331bc5:list:83780af0-e908-4c51-a1be-49d7e0ac5867:item:2,1",
    "_ObjectVersion_": "1",
    "FileSystemObjectType": 1,
    "Id": 2,
    "ServerRedirectedEmbedUri": null,
    "ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl": "",
    "DisplayName": "AB922B82-8406-4E49-B17B-9057BDF09503",
    "HasUniqueRoleAssignments": true,
    "Folder": {
      "_ObjectType_": "SP.Folder",
      "_ObjectIdentity_": "6b1fb39e-d0c3-7000-b3db-ec1021aca18d|740c6a0b-85e2-48a0-a494-e0f1759d4aa7:site:dc8ed2ac-dab3-4d38-a669-f2d9a8217dbf:web:9caa26cd-4dbb-43e0-9b41-26d384331bc5:folder:6facd266-57e5-4fea-9162-897b9cf2a0fc",
      "Exists": true,
      "IsWOPIEnabled": false,
      "ItemCount": 0,
      "Name": "AB922B82-8406-4E49-B17B-9057BDF09503",
      "ProgID": null,
      "ServerRelativeUrl": "/xxxx/Lists/PublishedFeed/AB922B82-8406-4E49-B17B-9057BDF09503",
      "TimeCreated": "/Date(1487190160000)/",
      "TimeLastModified": "/Date(1487190160000)/",
      "UniqueId": "/Guid(6facd266-57e5-4fea-9162-897b9cf2a0fc)/",
      "WelcomePage": ""
    },
    "File": null,
    "ContentType": {
      "_ObjectType_": "SP.ContentType",
      "_ObjectIdentity_": "6b1fb39e-d0c3-7000-b3db-ec1021aca18d|740c6a0b-85e2-48a0-a494-e0f1759d4aa7:site:dc8ed2ac-dab3-4d38-a669-f2d9a8217dbf:web:9caa26cd-4dbb-43e0-9b41-26d384331bc5:list:83780af0-e908-4c51-a1be-49d7e0ac5867:contenttype:0x0120000153FEC126436442892AABB21C3053F4",
      "Description": "Create a new folder.",
      "DisplayFormTemplateName": "ListForm",
      "DisplayFormUrl": "",
      "DocumentTemplate": "",
      "DocumentTemplateUrl": "",
      "EditFormTemplateName": "ListForm",
      "EditFormUrl": "",
      "Group": "Folder Content Types",
      "Hidden": false,
      "Id": {
        "_ObjectType_": "SP.ContentTypeId",
        "StringValue": "0x0120000153FEC126436442892AABB21C3053F4"
      },
      "JSLink": "",
      "MobileDisplayFormUrl": "",
      "MobileEditFormUrl": "",
      "MobileNewFormUrl": "",
      "Name": "Folder",
      "NewFormTemplateName": "ListForm",
      "NewFormUrl": "",
      "ReadOnly": false,
      "SchemaXml": "<ContentType ID=\"0x0120000153FEC126436442892AABB21C3053F4\" Name=\"Folder\" Group=\"Folder Content Types\" Description=\"Create a new folder.\" Sealed=\"TRUE\" Version=\"0\" DelayActivateTemplateBinding=\"GROUP,SPSPERS,SITEPAGEPUBLISHING\" FeatureId=\"{695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162}\"><Fields><Field ID=\"{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}\" Type=\"Computed\" DisplayName=\"Content Type\" Name=\"ContentType\" DisplaceOnUpgrade=\"TRUE\" RenderXMLUsingPattern=\"TRUE\" Sortable=\"FALSE\" SourceID=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3\" StaticName=\"ContentType\" Group=\"_Hidden\" PITarget=\"MicrosoftWindowsSharePointServices\" PIAttribute=\"ContentTypeID\" FromBaseType=\"TRUE\"><FieldRefs><FieldRef Name=\"ContentTypeId\"/></FieldRefs><DisplayPattern><MapToContentType><Column Name=\"ContentTypeId\"/></MapToContentType></DisplayPattern></Field><Field ID=\"{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}\" Type=\"Text\" Name=\"Title\" DisplayName=\"Title\" Required=\"FALSE\" SourceID=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3\" StaticName=\"Title\" FromBaseType=\"TRUE\" ColName=\"nvarchar1\" Hidden=\"TRUE\"/><Field ID=\"{8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8}\" Hidden=\"FALSE\" ShowInFileDlg=\"FALSE\" ShowInVersionHistory=\"FALSE\" Type=\"File\" Name=\"FileLeafRef\" DisplaceOnUpgrade=\"TRUE\" DisplayName=\"Name\" AuthoringInfo=\"(for use in forms)\" List=\"Docs\" FieldRef=\"ID\" ShowField=\"LeafName\" JoinColName=\"DoclibRowId\" JoinRowOrdinal=\"0\" JoinType=\"INNER\" NoCustomize=\"TRUE\" SourceID=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3\" StaticName=\"FileLeafRef\" FromBaseType=\"TRUE\" Required=\"TRUE\"/><Field ID=\"{b824e17e-a1b3-426e-aecf-f0184d900485}\" Name=\"ItemChildCount\" DisplaceOnUpgrade=\"TRUE\" ReadOnly=\"TRUE\" ShowInFileDlg=\"FALSE\" Type=\"Lookup\" DisplayName=\"Item Child Count\" List=\"Docs\" FieldRef=\"ID\" ShowField=\"ItemChildCount\" JoinColName=\"DoclibRowId\" JoinRowOrdinal=\"0\" JoinType=\"INNER\" SourceID=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3\" StaticName=\"ItemChildCount\" FromBaseType=\"TRUE\"/><Field ID=\"{960ff01f-2b6d-4f1b-9c3f-e19ad8927341}\" Name=\"FolderChildCount\" DisplaceOnUpgrade=\"TRUE\" ReadOnly=\"TRUE\" ShowInFileDlg=\"FALSE\" Type=\"Lookup\" DisplayName=\"Folder Child Count\" List=\"Docs\" FieldRef=\"ID\" ShowField=\"FolderChildCount\" JoinColName=\"DoclibRowId\" JoinRowOrdinal=\"0\" JoinType=\"INNER\" SourceID=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3\" StaticName=\"FolderChildCount\" FromBaseType=\"TRUE\"/></Fields><XmlDocuments><XmlDocument NamespaceURI=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms\"><FormTemplates xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms\"><Display>ListForm</Display><Edit>ListForm</Edit><New>ListForm</New></FormTemplates></XmlDocument></XmlDocuments></ContentType>",
      "Scope": "/xxxx/Lists/PublishedFeed",
      "Sealed": true,
      "StringId": "0x0120000153FEC126436442892AABB21C3053F4"
    },
    "ContentTypeId": {
      "_ObjectType_": "SP.ContentTypeId",
      "StringValue": "0x0120000153FEC126436442892AABB21C3053F4"
    },
    "Title": "AB922B82-8406-4E49-B17B-9057BDF09503",
    "_ModerationComments": null,
    "File_x0020_Type": null,
    "MicroBlogType": null,
    "PostAuthor": null,
    "DefinitionId": null,
    "RootPostID": null,
    "RootPostOwnerID": null,
    "RootPostUniqueID": null,
    "ReplyCount": null,
    "ReferenceID": null,
    "Attributes": null,
    "Content": null,
    "ContentData": null,
    "SearchContent": null,
    "RefRoot": null,
    "RefReply": null,
    "PostSource": null,
    "PeopleCount": null,
    "PeopleList": null,
    "MediaLinkType": null,
    "MediaLinkDescription": null,
    "PostSourceUri": null,
    "MediaLinkURI": null,
    "MediaLinkUISnippet": null,
    "MediaLinkContentURI": null,
    "MediaLength": null,
    "MediaWidth": null,
    "MediaHeight": null,
    "MediaPreviewWidth": null,
    "MediaPreviewHeight": null,
    "MediaActionWidth": null,
    "MediaActionHeight": null,
    "MediaActionClickUrl": null,
    "MediaActionClickKind": null,
    "eMailSubscribers": null,
    "eMailUnsubscribed": null,
    "RemoteLocation": null,
    "LikesCount": null,
    "LikedBy": null,
    "HashTags": {
      "_ObjectType_": "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection",
      "_Child_Items_": []
    },
    "j33b1bc20532487296f1bbbdead35a56": null,
    "TaxCatchAll$SP.FieldLookupValue$  Array": [],
    "TaxCatchAllLabel$SP.FieldLookupValue$  Array": [],
    "ComplianceAssetId": null,
    "ID$  Int32": 2,
    "Modified": "/Date(1487190160000)/",
    "Created": "/Date(1487190160000)/",
    "Author": {
      "_ObjectType_": "SP.FieldUserValue",
      "LookupId": 12,
      "LookupValue": "xxxxxxxxx",
      "Email": "xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    },
    "Editor": {
      "_ObjectType_": "SP.FieldUserValue",
      "LookupId": 12,
      "LookupValue": "xxxxxxxxx",
      "Email": "xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    },
    "_HasCopyDestinations": null,
    "_CopySource": null,
    "owshiddenversion$  Int32": 1,
    "WorkflowVersion$  Int32": 1,
    "_UIVersion$  Int32": 512,
    "_UIVersionString": "1.0",
    "Attachments": false,
    "_ModerationStatus$  Int32": 0,
    "InstanceID": null,
    "Order$ Double": 200,
    "GUID": "/Guid(e52decf3-c64b-4cd5-bad2-e1a40c812dae)/",
    "WorkflowInstanceID": null,
    "FileRef": "/xxxx/Lists/PublishedFeed/AB922B82-8406-4E49-B17B-9057BDF09503",
    "FileDirRef": "/xxxx/Lists/PublishedFeed",
    "Last_x0020_Modified": "2017-02-15T20:22:40Z",
    "Created_x0020_Date": "2017-02-15T20:22:40Z",
    "FSObjType": "1",
    "SortBehavior": {
      "_ObjectType_": "SP.FieldLookupValue",
      "LookupId": 2,
      "LookupValue": "1"
    },
    "FileLeafRef": "AB922B82-8406-4E49-B17B-9057BDF09503",
    "UniqueId": "/Guid(6facd266-57e5-4fea-9162-897b9cf2a0fc)/",
    "SyncClientId": {
      "_ObjectType_": "SP.FieldLookupValue",
      "LookupId": 2,
      "LookupValue": null
    },
    "ProgId": "",
    "ScopeId": "{19A9D84C-A79A-40DC-9E4D-2FE84DAB81E0}",
    "MetaInfo": "",
    "_Level$  Int32": 1,
    "_IsCurrentVersion": true,
    "ItemChildCount": "0",
    "FolderChildCount": "0",
    "Restricted": "",
    "OriginatorId": "",
    "NoExecute": "0",
    "ContentVersion": "0",
    "_ComplianceFlags": "",
    "_ComplianceTag": "",
    "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime": "",
    "_ComplianceTagUserId": "",
    "AccessPolicy": "",
    "_VirusStatus": "",
    "_VirusVendorID": "",
    "_VirusInfo": "",
    "AppAuthor": null,
    "AppEditor": null,
    "SMTotalSize": {
      "_ObjectType_": "SP.FieldLookupValue",
      "LookupId": 244,
      "LookupValue": ""
    },
    "SMLastModifiedDate": "2017-02-15T20:22:40Z",
    "SMTotalFileStreamSize": "0",
    "SMTotalFileCount": {
      "_ObjectType_": "SP.FieldLookupValue",
      "LookupId": 0,
      "LookupValue": ""
    }
  }
```

Why can't I fetch the Role assignments for the list item with C# CSOM code in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following code:

Note: change the data within "`<>`" to your information.

Ensure you are using latest SharePoint Online SDK (Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;


namespace ConnectingToO365 {  
    public class Program {  
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string siteURL = "https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>";
            string userName = "<user>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com"; 
            string password = "<password>"; 
            //Create the client context object and set the credentials  
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);  
            SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();  
            foreach(char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);  
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);  
            //Load the web  
            Web web = clientContext.Web;  
            clientContext.Load(web);  
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
            //Load the list
            List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("<list>");
            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            ListItem item = list.GetItemById(<id>);
            clientContext.Load(item, a => a.HasUniqueRoleAssignments,b => b.RoleAssignments.Include(roleAsg => roleAsg.Member.LoginName,
                    roleAsg => roleAsg.RoleDefinitionBindings.Include(roleDef => roleDef.Name,
                    roleDef => roleDef.Description)));
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            if (item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
            {

                foreach (var roleAsg in item.RoleAssignments){
                    Console.WriteLine("User/Group: " + roleAsg.Member.LoginName);
                    List<string> roles = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var role in roleAsg.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                    {
                        roles.Add(role.Description);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Permissions: " + string.Join(",", roles.ToArray()));
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------");
                    }
            }else{
                Console.WriteLine("No unique permission found");
            }

            Console.ReadKey(); 

        }  
    }  
}
```

**Update:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;


namespace ConnectingToO365 {  
    public class Program {  
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string siteURL = "https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>";
            string userName = "<user>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com"; 
            string password = "<password>"; 
            //Create the client context object and set the credentials  
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);  
            SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();  
            foreach(char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);  
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);  
            //Load the web  
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            //get all lists
            ListCollection collList = web.Lists;
            clientContext.Load(web);
            clientContext.Load(collList);
            clientContext.Load(collList, wc => wc.Include(w => w.HasUniqueRoleAssignments, w => w.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)); 
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (List oList in collList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-- List: {0} permissions:", oList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
                var listItems = oList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
                clientContext.Load(listItems, a => a.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(b => b.HasUniqueRoleAssignments),
                        permsn => permsn.Include(a => a.RoleAssignments.Include(roleAsg => roleAsg.Member.LoginName,
                        roleAsg => roleAsg.RoleDefinitionBindings.Include(roleDef => roleDef.Name,
                        roleDef => roleDef.Description))));
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (var item in listItems)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("List item: " + item["ID"]);
                    if (item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                    {
                        foreach (var roleAsg in item.RoleAssignments)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("User/Group: " + roleAsg.Member.LoginName);
                            List<string> roles = new List<string>();
                            foreach (var role in roleAsg.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                            {
                                roles.Add(role.Description);
                            }
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                            Console.WriteLine("Permissions: " + string.Join(",", roles.ToArray()));
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        Console.WriteLine("No unique permission found");
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("###############");
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey(); 

        }  
    }  
}
```

Use the site admins which has permissions on all lists in the site to run the commands.

Comment: yes this works for me. it also works for me when i search for the list via the title. but it does not work for me when the list does the lookup via the Object Identity. I believe I have uncovered a bug.

Comment: so in other words, you did this: 1) get list by title, 2) get list item by ID, 3) get list item role assignments. I did this: 1) get all lists in site, for each list: 2) get all list items in list. 3) get all list item role assignments if has unique role assignments.

Comment: Check my update. It  does this: 1) get all lists in site, for each list: 2) get all list items in list. 3) get all list item role assignments if has unique role assignments.

Comment: That also works for me, because this does not get the list item permissions via list item object identity. Here is the example based on your program that reproduces the bug: https://gist.github.com/nddipiazza/d9bda1ce849f38ae537dba2f7f192111

Comment: I tried your code and it works as expected. It returned the roles for items which have unique permissions. You can use the Fiddler to trace the requests to see what is failing. And you can add Breakpoints into your code to debug the code. Check step by step.

Comment: By the way, in your code, you have loaded the list items with properties of each item (item ID and so on)  in a single server request. Why do you need to load each item again instead of loading its permissions in this request too? It loads the role assignments for every items, so it includes multiple server requests, you can also load the list items and its permissions in single server request call (refer to my code).

Comment: really? it doesn't work for me. i got plenty of `Error: Expected to have unique permissions but couldn't find them!` message indicating the block of code where it hit the condition where HasUniquePermissions was true, but the list item permissions failed to be found. 
and to answer your other question i am not actually using c# code for anything. i am merely using it to demonstrate that the fiddler request i pasted above does not work for sharepoint online. in my question, you will see the fiddler request that fails. can you possibly send me the fiddler for your example usage of this program?

Comment: my app directly makes WCF web service requests. we can make list item role assignment queries against a list item object identity in sharepoint on prem. but not sharepoint online. seems like a bug to me?

Comment: I have tested it using c# console application and it works in SPO. It's strange.Have your tired using another admin account for testing?

Comment: no... i just have the one account available to me. i could make a request to have someone else try it. so when you ran it, you didn't see my message write to the console `Error: Expected to have unique permissions but couldn't find them!` ?

Comment: I tried it on some other sharepoint sites. i can see permissions. i think my other test instance is just garbage somehow? but glad to see it's working. see also https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f8893f51-6aac-417b-a09a-a7e06910314b/csom-sharepoint-online-unable-to-get-list-item-role-assignments?forum=sharepointgeneral for more info